# How to apply custom css to split post into multiple page

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

my website is web.guru99.com

i have split post into multiple page by `<!–nextpage–>` now i want to apply custom style for good look and feel

i have search all over but does not find any helpful content and i am trying to solve this

from 2 weeks.but did not succeeded

right now pagination look like this – http://screencast.com/t/onGdJWET

and i want somewhat like this – http://screencast.com/t/GAqxExyivB

so how can I achieve it.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.pagination_split_post span {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
border: 1px solid gray;
margin-left: 5px;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 10px;
background: #64a9dc;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px gray;
color: white;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px gray;
}

.pagination_split_post a span {
background: white;
color: gray;
}
```